# Merging lines after using split lines at points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I have a big hydrologic network that I split using the split lines at points tool with a file of points placed along the lines every 100 meters. But when I do that I have a big amount of smaller lines that appeared (and not just because some lines have their last segment thats too short to be separated in 100m segments). I'm not quite sure why they appear but I was wondering if there was a way to select the smaller lines (say the one smaller than 20m) and merge them to the closest adjacent big segment of line.

Do you know if there is a way to do that ?

I was told to use "eliminate" with the line option but I dont see it on the tool's window (see picture).

What can I do to have that option ?

[image]

Comment: Are these stored in a geodatabase? You could use the shapelength property to select them. As for merge --- maybe loop though the remaining lines and look for overlapping endpoints? You can add the endpoints to the layer using [Add Geometry Attributes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm)

Comment: I can store them in a gdb for sure ! But once I have selected the smaller segments will Add Geometry attributes make a segment of 105m if I have a segment of 100m and on of 5m next to each other ?

Comment: No, the Add Geometry Attributes will just make it clear where the endpoints for each line segment are located. These could be used to help select the short lines and their adjacent lines (for the Eliminate tool in @ahmadhanb's answer) based on their common end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an advance license, you can to use [Eliminate tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/eliminate.htm). You need to select the lines that you want to be eliminated.

Based on the help above'

> With the **LINE** option, Eliminate merges selected arcs separated by
>   pseudo nodes into single arcs.

Comment: I have an advance license but it seems this tool only works with polygons (I'm using arcgis 10.5). Is it possible ?

Comment: Just wanted to highlight ahmadhanb's answer above in response to your comment -- use feature_type = LINE per that tool's help page.